# NServiceBus Saga Not Found

Tags: nservicebus-sagas

I have vs 2015, NServiceBus 4.6.0.0, RavenDb 2.5.

I deployed a new release of my software and 1 saga is experiencing saga not found errors on at least two messages associated with the saga. When we rollback the release the messages are reprocessed without error.

I have used some c# code to access the saga data and that works fine. There are 600+ sagas in our production RavenDb. So I believe that rules out RavenDb as the problem and eliminates any changes to the saga object tree contributing to this issue.

so it looks like we are back at NServiceBus. I am at loss of what would cause these saga not found errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Additionally, We are using .Net Framework 4.6.1

Comment: What has changed in the new version of your code? Are you updating to a different version of NServiceBus/RavenDB?

Comment: stack overflow is not really a great medium for helping people troubleshoot such specific scenarios. If you still need help with this, can you try one of the support options listed at https://particular.net/support

Comment: Well we solve the problem. it was not some ethereal problem in the bowels of  NServiceBus or Raven it was a design problem. The Message Handler was for a specific saga... System function. The message was being sent out for various system functions. This means that some the messages were not related to this saga at all. Hence the error.